# Adding multiple new columns to an existing dataframe base on a given condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Dataframe with the below column names, and I want to create new columns(**n_1, n_2, n_3     n_4, n_5, n_6, n_7, n_8**) off the original Dataframe based on a given condition. The condition is to create new columns for each unique **EVENT_ID** in the Dataframe. check for rows in the **SELECTION_TRAP** column that has 1 as a value, take the **BSP** value that corresponds to the row, and insert it into an **n_1**, if **SELECTION_TRAP** value is 2, insert into **n_2** the **BSP** that corresponds to that row. same applies to **n_3,n_4, n_5, n_6, n_7, n_8**.

```
EVENT_ID    BSP   SELECTION_TRAP    
174331755   34.00   1
174331755   5.18    2
174331755   3.30    7
174331755   70.00   4
174331755   19.10   3
174331755   13.00   6
174331755   2.96    8       
174329130   14.00   5
174329130   8.20    7
174329130   3.65    1
174329130   3.15    4
174329130   7.20    2
174329130   13.50   8
174339802   160.00  3
174339802   47.57   7
174339802   88.01   8
174339802   1.58    5
174339802   268.86  2
174339802   19.14   4
174339802   4.66    1
174339802   17.77   6
```

Expected Output:

```
EVENT_ID      n_1    n_2       n_3     n_4     n_5    n_6     n_7     n_8
174331755    34.00   5.18     19.10   70.00    0.00   13.00   3.30    2.96
174329130    3.65    7.20     0.00    3.15     14.00  0.00    8.20    13.50
174339802    4.66    268.86   160.00  19.14    1.58   17.77   47.57   88.01
```

I tried the below code but the output is way off from my expected output. I can figure a pandas function I can use to achieve this asap. please I need you help on this. thanks

```
for j,n in enumerate(new.index):
    if df['SELECTION_TRAP'].values[j] == 1:
        df['1'] = df['BSP'].values[j]
    elif df['SELECTION_TRAP'].values[j] == 2:
        df['2'] = df['BSP'].values[j]
    elif df['SELECTION_TRAP'].values[j] == 3:
        df['3'] = df['BSP'].values[j]
    elif df['SELECTION_TRAP'].values[j] == 4:
        df['4'] = df['BSP'].values[j]
    elif df['SELECTION_TRAP'].values[j] == 5:
        df['5'] = df['BSP'].values[j]
    elif df['SELECTION_TRAP'].values[j] == 6:
        df['6'] = df['BSP'].values[j]
    elif df['SELECTION_TRAP'].values[j] == 7:
        df['7'] = df['BSP'].values[j]
    elif df['SELECTION_TRAP'].values[j] == 8:
        df['8'] = df['BSP'].values[j]
    else:
        df[['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8']] = df[['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8']].apply(0,axis = 1)




EVENT_ID    BSP   S_TRAP  3     7         8      5        2       4      1        6                             
174339802   160.00  3   160.00  47.57   88.01   1.58    268.86  19.14   4.66    17.77
174339802   47.57   7   160.00  47.57   88.01   1.58    268.86  19.14   4.66    17.77
174339802   88.01   8   160.00  47.57   88.01   1.58    268.86  19.14   4.66    17.77
174339802   1.58    5   160.00  47.57   88.01   1.58    268.86  19.14   4.66    17.77
174339802   268.86  2   160.00  47.57   88.01   1.58    268.86  19.14   4.66    17.77
174339802   19.14   4   160.00  47.57   88.01   1.58    268.86  19.14   4.66    17.77
174339802   4.66    1   160.00  47.57   88.01   1.58    268.86  19.14   4.66    17.77
174339802   17.77   6   160.00  47.57   88.01   1.58    268.86  19.14   4.66    17.77
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isn't this a `pivot_table()` output?

```
df.pivot_table(index="EVENT_ID",columns="SELECTION_TRAP",values="BSP",fill_value=0).add_prefix('n_').reset_index()
```

---

```
SELECTION_TRAP   EVENT_ID    n_1     n_2    n_3  ...    n_5    n_6    n_7    n_8
0               174329130   3.65    7.20    0.0  ...  14.00   0.00   8.20  13.50
1               174331755  34.00    5.18   19.1  ...   0.00  13.00   3.30   2.96
2               174339802   4.66  268.86  160.0  ...   1.58  17.77  47.57  88.01
```

Comment: This is awesome, just in line with the expected result. thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use a pivot table and add prefixes once that's done.

```
df.pivot_table(index='EVENT_ID',columns='SELECTION_TRAP',values='BSP').add_prefix('n_')
```

Output

```
SELECTION_TRAP    n_1     n_2    n_3    n_4    n_5    n_6    n_7    n_8
EVENT_ID                                                               
174329130        3.65    7.20    NaN   3.15  14.00    NaN   8.20  13.50
174331755       34.00    5.18   19.1  70.00    NaN  13.00   3.30   2.96
174339802        4.66  268.86  160.0  19.14   1.58  17.77  47.57  88.01
​
```

Comment: This is perfect. just as expected, I never knew I can achieve this with just a one-line function, thanks.